# Перевести строку в массив

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно сгенерированную строку перевести в массив

```
$carr = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id,t,b,ty,msg,log FROM `comm` ORDER BY id DESC");
$comm = 'array( ';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($carr)) {
$comm .= "array('id'=>$row[id], 't'=>$t, 'text'=>'$row[msg]'), ";
}
$comm .= ")";
print_r($comm);
```

На выходе:

```
array( array('id'=>4, 't'=>NULL, 'text'=>'11111111111111111111'), array('id'=>3, 't'=>NULL, 'text'=>'1111111111111'), array('id'=>2, 't'=>NULL, 'text'=>'Тестик'), )
```

Соответственно, определяется как строка. как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$carr = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id,t,msg as text FROM `comm` ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($carr)) {
  $comm[] = $row;
}
print_r($comm);
```

или

```
$carr = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id,t,msg as text FROM `comm` ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($carr, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $comm[] = $row;
}
print_r($comm);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$carr = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id,t,b,ty,msg,log FROM `comm` ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($carr)) {
  $comm[] = $row;
}

print_r($comm);
```

Также в цикле переменная `$t` всегда будет NULL, правильно будет `$row['t']`

Comment: выдаёт немного неверно, выбраны все значения и массив вида `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [id] => 4
            [1] => 0`... а нужно `array(  array('id'=>1, 't'=>NULL, 'text'=>'Тестик'),
                    array('id'=>2, 't'=>1,      'text'=>'Child'),  `...